# No response Data Angularjs POST / TypeScript

Tags: angularjs, post, typescript, response

I'm trying to test AngularJS's post method out, but so far I have not figured out how to get it work.

Here is my code snippet.

```
 parameter = { categoryName: '' }; <- just a dummy parameter purposely set to '' for testing purposes

            this.httpService({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '/svc_templates/svc_fetch_category.php',<- Just echoing some JSON string.
                data: parameter
            }).then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
```

The response I'm getting is shown below.

[image: Console.log(response) output]

It seems that a call to the php file is going through, but the actual data(JSON) is not returning for some reason...

Could anyone help me out?

Comment: Have you checked the Developer tools network tab what is he response from the PHP script?

Comment: I just checked it, but there was no response returned from the script.
When I modify my code from POST to GET, it works.
Is this supposed to happen when using HTTP methods like POST and GET?

Comment: Both POST and GET can return data. The issue is why your PHP script is not returning anything, can't see inside there unfortunately.

Comment: I just checked my script once again, it turned out there was a bug.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the server `.php` file is actually working using `curl` e.g.:

```
curl -X POST -d @filename.txt http://example.com/svc_templates/svc_fetch_category.php --header "Content-Type:application/json"
```

Where `filename.txt` contains the JSON data you want to send.